# Cannot reference a post with proper base address in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am trying to reference a post in my github pages site `http://myuser.github.io/myproj/` with Jekyll:

```
{% post_url 2016-03-21-mypost %}
```

This will point to `http://myuser.github.io/post/2016/03/21/mypost.html` which is wrong, as it should point to: `http://myuser.github.io/myproj/post/2016/03/21/mypost.html`. Thus I tried:

```
{% (post_url 2016-03-21-mypost) | prepend: site.baseurl %}
```

Where `site.baseurl` is `/myproj`. But it fails:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 26): Tag '{% (post_url
>   2016-03-21-mypost) | prepend: site.baseurl %}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%}/ in /home/myuser/Git/myproj/_posts/2016-03-21-mypost.md

How can I reference my post with the base address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a filter to a tag `{% %}` except for the `assign` tag `{% assign myvar = 'toto' | capitalize %}`.

Try : `{{ site.baseurl }}{% post_url 2016-03-21-mypost %}`